.NetMAUI the authentication of the loginpage only working in windows but incase of android emulator doesn't work why?what is the reason for that?
if i login it doesn't reach the backend server in ASP.NetCore
In a android emulator when am entering the username and password it can check the username and password at the backend ASPNetCore server then only allow the user.to fix the connection failure issue in a android emulator.
